# Is the normal fiber cone of any $\mathfrak m$-primary ideal Noetherian?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, graded-rings, integral-extensions

For an ideal $I$ in a commutative Noetherian ring $R$, let $\overline I$ be the [integral closure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_closure_of_an_ideal) of $I$.

Now for an ideal $I$ in a Noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak m)$ consider the graded ring $\bar {\mathcal F}(I):=\oplus_{n \ge 0} \overline {I^n}/\mathfrak m\overline{I^n}$.

My question is:

> If $\sqrt I=\mathfrak m$, then is $\bar {\mathcal F}(I)$ always a Noetherian ring ?

I know this is true if $R$ is [analytically unramified](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytically_unramified_ring), but am not sure what happens otherwise.

Please help.

Comment: Is there a cohomological interpretation of this  ?

Comment: @Arnaud ETEVE: there could be but not any I'm aware of ...